# DynamoDB best solution to making queries without using the primary key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have a table in DyamoDB similar to this:

```
StaffID, Name,          Email,              Office
1514923  Winston Smith, SmithW@company.com, 101
```

It only has around 100 rows.

I'm experimenting with Amazon's Alexa and the possibility of using it for voice-based queries such as

> 'Where is Winston Smith?'

The problem is that when using an Alexa function to pull results from the table, it would never be through the primary key `StaffID` - because you wouldn't have users asking:

> 'Where is 1514923?'

From what I've read, querying the non-primary key values is extremely slow... Is there a suitable solution to this when using Python with DynamoDB?

I know that with only 100 rows it is negligible - but I'd like to do things in the correct, industry standard way. Or is the best solution with cases like this, to simply scan the tables - splitting them up for different user groups when they get too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches here, depending on your application:

1. If you only ever want to query this table via the `Name` field, then change the table so that it has a partition key of `Name` instead of `StaffID`. DynamoDB isn't SQL - there's no need to have everything keyed on an ID field unless you actually use it. (Note you can't actually "change" the partition key on an existing DynamoDB table - you'll have to rebuild the table).
2. If you want to query efficiently via both `StaffID` and `Name`, create a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) for the table using the `Name` field. Be aware that global secondary indexes need both their own provisioned throughput and storage, both of which of course equal money.

Minor aside: this is nothing to do with the fact you're using the Python interface, it applies to all DynamoDB access.

Comment: What about cases where there are two records with the same name?

Comment: That's an application problem. Which answer do you want?